# How to updated deleted files on Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I'm working on a project in Rails and was using a CSS framework that came with some images.  I later decided to use something else and no longer need the images.  I deleted them, committed my changes to github but now every time I I commit to github it pulls the files I already deleted.  How do I keep it from doing that?  I want those changes gone for good, not readded to my project every time I merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing a force push.  I don't understand the problem but I forcing the push fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After committed have you push your change to repository. Please do following

```
delete images
git status
```

You will see files changed are comming in status, if images comming than go head and continue, you can either run `git add .` to add all files or

```
git add images_name_or_folder
```

git commit -m "Removed images"
git push

```
Now check and do `git pull` to check if all images gone.
```

Comment: Yes I pushed after I deleted the files and committed.  Problem is the files weren't deleted on github. So now it wants to make me pull the files back down before I can push anything new.

Comment: I fixed this by doing a force push.

Comment: ok great, there are few answer you should chose one so it should not come in list of unanswers.